# Banner graphic won't fill container responsively

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a page on a test site I'm setting up very similar to the same page on the live site. Both sites use the Divi theme set up as a child theme. The top banner of the page is supposed to dynamically resize to stay inside its container. On the live site this is fine, but on the test site it is not.

Compare the live site page at

https://www.intechrahealth.com/product/fenfast-375/

to its counterpart at

https://ab-intechrahealth.pantheonsite.io/product/fenfast-375/

Notice on the "ab" site, the top product banner is a static size and won't fill its container like it does on the live site.

I've compared the code and Divi layout setup on both sites. The Divi layout setup is identical on both. However, on the "ab" site, in Chrome Inspector for that image, a separate stylesheet "style-cpt.css" is referenced via the inactive parent theme. It appears that a custom post type stylesheet is being imposed on the "ab" site that isn't on the live site. However, the CSS in the style-cpt.css file is not taking precedence anyway and is getting crossed out in Inspector, so no matter whether I delete or alter or move that stylesheet to the active child theme, the result never changes.

I'm looking for help on getting unstuck. What can I do next to get these sites to agree as to responsiveness of the banner?

Comment: do you know how to use the console to debug? The issue is your div where the banner is you have an `!important` tag to 1080px and also you have it at 90% on another div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code

```
<div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0">
                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_0    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">


                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_code et_pb_code_0">


                <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
                    <img class="productBanner" src="https://ab-intechrahealth.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/fenfast-banner-new-1.jpg" alt="">
                </div> <!-- .et_pb_code_inner -->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_code -->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->


            </div>
```

change it to this

```
<div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_1 et_pb_fullwidth_section et_section_regular">




                    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_fullwidth_code et_pb_fullwidth_code_0">


                <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
                    <img class="productBanner lazyloading" src="https://ab-intechrahealth.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/fenfast-banner-new-1.jpg" alt="" data-was-processed="true">
                </div>
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_fullwidth_code -->


            </div>
```

Works fine with me have a look at the image

[image]

Comment: Oh! That revealed what I hadn't seen before. In the Divi Library, when creating the new layout on the "ab" site, I had chosen the wrong type of layout. I chose "section" when I ought to have chosen "layout". That gives me the Full Width section in the Divi template whereas "section" does not. I've just verified that this change does fix the problem. Now, unfortunately, I have to manually copy/paste all the settings from one layout to the other. Thanks!